# Update/insert value using trigger where PK autoincrement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm working with my first database and already have a problem. I have several tables. Some of them have PK set to autoincrement, others have `nvarchar()` type.

I have created trigger, which update or insert value into cell. This trigger works when I manually insert value for PF, in my case for `nvarchar()` values. It is not working for PK, where is set to autoincrement - `int`. I need help to create trigger which will work for that typs.

Example of trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Table_Name_trigger_update]
ON [dbo].[Table_Name]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE Table_Name
   SET
      changed_date = getdate()
    , changed_user  = CURRENT_USER
   FROM inserted AS ij
   WHERE ij.ID_name  = Table_Name.ID_name

   RETURN
END
```

So as I write earlier, this work on `nvarchar()`, where I manually insert PK. In that case trigger update the `getdate()` and `CURRENT_USER` value in table.

Comment: The "auto-increment" `INT IDENTITY` column doesn't need to be set - SQL Server takes care of that itself.

Comment: If you insert a new record, doesn't the trigger need to be `AFTER INSERT` then?

Comment: @NickyvV yes. I have 2 triggers. One for update (upper triger) and one for insert (almost the same as upper code) and I here I just paste the `update` trigger.

Comment: At the end, I think that this trigger actually work. When I insert data in table, where PK is `int`, the `created_user` and `current_date` does nothing, doesn't change. But if I refresh this table, I can see the name and date filled in the field. When I insert data in table when PK is `nvarchar`  I can see immediately see the the `created_use`r and `curent_date` values, but not in tables with `int` PK. That is why I assumed this trigger doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this trigger actually.
Try to replace it with these Default Constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR changed_date
GO

ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD DEFAULT (CURRENT_USER) FOR changed_user
GO
```

Comment: Instead of `CURRENT_USER` i would suggest to use `SUSER_SNAME()`, which is  more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without a trigger as @GriGrim already stated. But i would suggest another solution:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR changed_date
GO

ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD DEFAULT (SUSER_SNAME()) FOR changed_user
GO
```

You can compare the results using this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER, SUSER_SNAME()
```

`CURRENT_USER` tends to return `dbo` not the real username.